# What is the sound of teeth hitting each other in cold weather called?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the sound of teeth called that occurs in chilly weather: the sound that comes due to teeth crashing in each other in an extremely chilly winter.

Answer (score 101):

The most common and idiomatic word to describe this situation is ***chattering***.

From [WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=Chatter&i=3&h=00000000%23c):

> **chatter**: *click together repeatedly or uncontrollably*
>
> "Chattering teeth"

Comment: I'm not sure I can accept that without a reference and a few cites.

Comment: Getting there, @deadrat. I usually post the answer first and then go get some sources to support it.

Comment: I wasn't serious.  I guess I'm going to have to learn how to use emoticons.

Comment: I didn't know that you were kidding, but it didn't matter: you were absolutely right, and at no point was I offended. I post comments like yours all the time, and I wouldn't like to make a hypocrite of myself! I don't like to post answers which are supported solely by the implicit notion of "... take my word for it!".

Comment: Absolutely right?  No, not if you took me seriously.

Answer (score 26):

[Chatter](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/britannico/chatter) is the word you are looking for:

Chatter (teeth):

> - If your teeth chatter, they knock together repeatedly because you are very cold or frightened:
>
>   - *I could hardly talk, my teeth were chattering so much.*

Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 9):

I've also heard [**Clatter**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clatter) used for this.

> A continuous rattling sound as of hard objects falling or striking each other:

[image]

From [Google books](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22clattering%20teeth%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=lcS5VdKjNIaC7gaB95nwAg) the following quote

> “'Who are you?' I asked through clattering teeth. I was shivering from head to toe.

Comment: That is definitely a word that describes a sound, but I don't think I've ever seen it applied to the activity of teeth when one is cold or shivering.

Comment: [Google Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chattering+teeth%2Cclattering+teeth&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchattering%20teeth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclattering%20teeth%3B%2Cc0) suggests it's rare relative to **Chattering** but does get used. I must have read a lot of books from the 1890s. (;

Comment: Haha, fair enough.  Upvoted.  If you add the nGram link and image/chart to your answer, you might get others' upvotes as well.